# How do I fix this error where I want to render templates which have static files

Tags: python, django

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{% static, '/css/main.css'%} ">

     </head> <body> include 'accounts/navbar.html' %}   <div class="container-fluid"> block content %}



endblock %}
    </div>  <hr>    <h5>Our footer</h5>      </body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> </html>
```

I wanted to render a page and it brought the following output.

```
Invalid block tag on line 8: 'static,'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? Request Method:    GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Django Version:  4.2.4 Exception Type:   TemplateSyntaxError Exception Value:     Invalid block tag on line 8: 'static,'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? Exception Location:   C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 568, in invalid_block_tag Raised during:   accounts.views.home Python Executable:  C:\Python311\python.exe Python Version: 3.11.4 Python Path:  ['D:\\My_django_stuff\\crm',  'C:\\Python311\\python311.zip',  'C:\\Python311\\DLLs',  'C:\\Python311\\Lib',  'C:\\Python311',  'C:\\Users\\PATRICK -BITS\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\site-packages',  'C:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages',  'C:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\vboxapi-1.0-py3.11.egg'] Server time:   Fri, 11 Aug 2023 11:15:54 +0000<html> <head>    <title>CRM</title>  <link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect.  It's not `endblock %}`, it is `{% endblock %}`

Comment: As @raphael said, `include`, `static`, `blocks` all should be put into ```{% %}```. And you also didn't specify start of your `<head>` tag.

And, the statement: ```{% static, '/css/main.css'%}``` - shouldn't contain a comma, if you've set **STATIC_URL = '/static/'** with a trailing slash then you don't need to prefix an extra slash

Answer (score 0):

You should check your code once again, It is kind of messy and several syntax error

So lets debunk it

Before:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{% static, '/css/main.css'%} ">

     </head> <body> include 'accounts/navbar.html' %}   <div class="container-fluid"> block content %}



endblock %}
    </div>  <hr>    <h5>Our footer</h5>      </body>
```

After:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> #Not sure why your head start tag is missing ?
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{% static 'css/main.css'%} "> #Static dont need coma (*Static,* --> *Static*), and you dont need to add / before css, asuming you settings.py STATIC_URL = '/static/'
</head> 
<body> {% include 'accounts/navbar.html' %}  #{% dont forget this
<div class="container-fluid"> 
{% block content %} #{% dont forget this
{% endblock %} #{% dont forget this
</div>
<hr>
<h5>Our footer</h5>
</body>
```

Please read the comments

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/
https://www.w3schools.com/django/ref_tags_block.php

Comment: Worked like magic thanks for your support